# Where can I get Chocolate Bar shaped silicone molds from in the UK?

Tags: equipment, mold, fudge

I need to find some chocolate bar shaped silicone molds, ideally about 100 grams in each bar,  although I could go for smaller bars but not much.

Could you please let me know where I can get some from in the UK as I could do with ordering them by the weekend, only I have got fudge bars I need to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon have a couple:

[http://www.amazon.co.uk/Silikomart-Silicone-Easy-Tablette-Mould/dp/B002VLQNBQ/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1320833045&sr=8-4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002VLQNBQ)

[http://www.amazon.co.uk/ScrapCooking%C2%AE-Silicone-Bakeware-Chocolate-Tablets/dp/B0058GI0BW/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1320833045&sr=8-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058GI0BW)

Answer (score 0):

The Cake Decorating Company in Nottingham sell a wide range of moulds.

http://www.thecakedecoratingcompany.co.uk/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=209_348&products_id=3628

I've done business with them and can recommend them.